# What is the nullity of an onto transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a $5 \times 13$ matrix, with $T(x) = Ax$, what is the nullity of $A$ if $T$ is onto?
I can't figure out what it would be...

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yeah, the number of columns in the original matrix is equal to the rank plus the nullity @T.Bongers

Comment: It's onto, so what's the rank?

Comment: @T.Bongers - Is the rank the same as the number of rows for onto?

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is onto, then $\operatorname{im}(T) = \mathbb{R}^5,$ so $\dim(\operatorname{im}(T)) = 5.$ Apply the Rank-Nullity Theorem (as T. Bongers suggested) to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $T:\mathbb R^{12}\to\mathbb R^5$ is linear. Moreover, $\operatorname{rank}T=5$ since $T$ is assumed to be onto. Now, the Rank-Nullity theorem states
$$
\operatorname{rank}T+\operatorname{null} T=12
$$
Putting all this together, what can we say about $\operatorname{null}T$?